# Submitting HTML form in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I am using the following code to submit form in my `WebBrowser`:

```
    private void wbMain_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wbMain.Url.AbsoluteUri))
        {
            wbMain.Document.GetElementById("dp").SetAttribute("checked", "checked");
            MessageBox.Show("checked");
            wbMain.Document.GetElementById("frm").InvokeMember("submit");
        }
    }
```

It was working perfect, but after removing the `MessageBox` form is not submitting any more. I don't know why, maybe because submitting is being invoked when the form is not full loaded?

What can you suggest?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but unfortunately didn't figure out what exactly was wrong. 
It looks like calling MessageBox.Show() triggers a chain of events, which makes the WebBrowser "update" its state.

My solution was instead of invoking member, executing appropriate javascript.

And did you try this?

```
while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, brat :). Actually I already figured it out and added `Application.DoEvents();` right before submitting form.